# ld library problem

Tags: centos, libraries, hacking, security

I am getting the below error while checking status of any service or stoping starting any server on my linux server. Its CentOS-5.4 server.

```
sh: /usr/bin/(swapd): /lib/ld-linux.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have checked ls -l /lib/ld* and below is the o/p

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root       129832 Oct 25 19:16 ld-2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root            9 Nov 24 02:14 ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           13 Nov 24 02:14 ld-lsb.so.3 -> ld-linux.so.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, your system is hacked.

`/usr/bin/(swapd)` is a trojan/exploit that links to the ancient, pre-glibc libc5 which CentOS 5 doesn't have.

Comment: +1,000,000. This is almost certainly the case. The current version of CentOS is 5.5, and CentOS does not provide patches for older point versions: you need to update, and stay up to date so that this doesn't happen again.